# Seam does not capture the ViewExpiredException

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, seam

I'm using the JSF 1.2 + Seam 2.2.1 and JBossAS 4.0.4.

I have the following entry in the file pages.xml:

```
<exception>
    <end-conversation/>
    <redirect view-id="/facelets/error.xhtml"/>
</exception>
```

But if I click on a commandLink and a commandButton after the session has expired, the server throws the following exception:

```
12:19:09,671 WARN  [lifecycle] executePhase(RESTORE_VIEW 1,com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl@1d7187f) threw exception
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/facelets/login.xhtml - View /facelets/login.xhtml could not be restored.
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:187)
```

It may also be worth noting, that no response get returned whatsoever.

I have already tried to catch the catch the exception explicitly, but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found this while searching for error handling with Seam a while back

```
    <\!-\- Now we specify the super class of all Exceptions: java.lang.Exception.  This will catch all exceptions. \-->
    <\!-\- But it will give us access to the Exception to retrieve its contents for display to the screen.         \--> 
  <exception class="java.lang.Exception">
      <\!-\- still a good idea to end the "conversation" rather than leaving it open ended. \-->
      <end-conversation/>
        <\!-\- now we redirect to the current page. The code for this is in the next example. \-->
      <redirect view-id="#{viewId.currentValue}">
        <\!-\- specify the message severity as error.  Also the expression language used below allows us to "grab"-->      
        <\!-\- the exception that was captured above and then pass it to the h:message tag for display to the end \-->    
        <\!-\- user.  Much nicer than a debug screen.                                                             \-->     
        <message severity="error">
          #{org.jboss.seam.handledException.message}
        </message>
      </redirect>
  </exception>
```

With this you should actually be able to catch everything and expose it for what it is. the `viewId.currentValue` thing is a piece of code we used to write to the current page, but you could redirect to wherever you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link on [Seam's community site](http://seamframework.org/Community/JavaxfacesapplicationViewExpiredException) where they are discussing a similar problem. Perhaps your answer is there? They cover a couple of different solutions, depending on where the problem stems from.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following in pages.xml:

```
<exception class="javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException">
    <redirect view-id="/pages/login.xhtml">
        <message severity="error">Your session has timed out, please Log-In again</message>
    </redirect>
</exception>
```